# how can n=1 be the parameter of a function

Tags: python, function, parameters

I was doing an online course for python and on the functions part of the course, they made two functions (one for determining prime numbers and one printing them)

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True

def primes(n=1):
   while(True):
       if isprime(n): yield n
       n += 1 

for n in primes():
    if n > 100: break
    print(n)
```

what i don't understand is the parameter of the function `primes`. Why is it `n=1`. I'm new to programming in general as you could probably tell and I'm not very knowledgeable on functions and generators. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a default value. If a parameter is passed to the function it will behave "normally", otherwise it will use the default.

```
def my_print(num=1):
    print num

my_print()
>> 1

my_print(7)
>> 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyword argument in the function call means a match by name, and in the
function header it specifies a default for an optional argument.